# Worklight WL.Server.invokeHttp() with DELETE method doesn't accept query param

Tags: http, ibm-mobilefirst, query-string, http-delete

I have a Worklight adapter that calls a RESTful method through `WL.Server.invokeHttp()`.  When an http DELETE method is used, the query string parameters do not get added.  I'm on Worklight 6.0.

The input is setup like so:

```
{
   "headers": {
      "Accept": "application\/json",
      "Authorization": "Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "Content-Type": "application\/json"
   },
   "method": "delete",
   "parameters": {
      "messageIds": "r11118,r11119"
   },
   "path": "\/myMessages\/v2\/messages" 
}

and called like: var result=WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
```

But I can see from [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) that the query params don't get added:

```
  DELETE /myMessages/v2/messages HTTP/1.1\r\n
```

If all I do is change the method to a GET, the params are there on Wireshark:

```
  GET /myMessages/v2/messages?messageIds=r11118%2Cr11119 HTTP/1.1\r\n
```

Comment: If you are an IBM customer and in need of this fix Anton mentioned below, consider opening a PMR.

Comment: Thanks Matt, will be handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a bug. We'll investigate it and fix in next releases if confirmed.

Comment: Bug is confirmed. Will be fixed in future releases.