# Worklight adapter invoke Http DELETE Method not working

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, http-delete

Refer this link.
[Worklight WL.Server.invokeHttp() with DELETE method doesn't accept query param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578952/worklight-wl-server-invokehttp-with-delete-method-doesnt-accept-query-param)
I am adding content in body ,but i am getting 500 response.Same request is working from postman and other clients.I think this is an issue with worklight.

My request :

```
HEADERS
Accept: xxxx
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Consumer: xxx
Content-Length: 199
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Contract: x
Cookie: xxxxx
User-Agent: runscope/0.1

PARAMETERS
list: {xxx:xxxx}
BODY view formatted
list= {xxx:xxx}
```

Implementation Code:

```
var input = {
   method : 'delete',
   returnedContentType : 'xml',
   path : 'xxx'

   headers : {
    Accept : 'xxx',
    Consumer : 'xxx',
    Contract : 'x',
    Cookie : xxx,
    contentType : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
   },



      body : {
       contentType : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
       content : 'list={"one": "two","key": "value"}'
    }
  };

var response = WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
```

Comment: Worklight version- 6.2.0.0

Comment: And the build number...?

Comment: com.worklight.studio.plugin_6.2.0.00-20140724-2139.

Comment: Please edit the question with the adapter implementation code that you're trying to invoke with the DELETE method.

Comment: Can you also try with the latest version, Worklight 6.2 Fix Pack 2?

Comment: okies .I will update current version

Comment: i have updated current version.But still its not working.

Comment: I also add my implemetation code please check.

Comment: I am getting HTTP Response Code 500 i.e Internal Server Error.The same requested is working fine from hurl.it and postman and i am getting 200 response and items are deleted from server.

Comment: But all other Http method are working like post,put and get.If i send List in  Parameters then it returns 403.So i think its an issue with DELETE method.

Comment: Could you provide a working example of DELETE method?

Comment: I don't have it at this time. Can you upload your adapter somewhere to be inspected? Developers will look at it at the beginning of the work week.

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP DELETE method is not allowed to use any content provided in the body.  Therefore it is not surprising that the server would return an error.  Technically, the response should be a 400, not a 500.